# how to make gauge in tableau using background image?

Tags: excel, background-image, gauge, tableau-api

i know that gauges are not a good way to represent data. But our clients demanded to have gauge in dashboard. we recommended bullet charts but it's of no use. the gauge should take input from excel file and show respected data on gauge. so can anyone please guide me to accomplish the task.

Appreciate any suggestion on how to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bullet charts are a much better alternative, but here's a fun blog entry showing how to make gauges in Tableau

http://duelingdata.blogspot.com/2013/05/gauge-hate.html